# Replace pasted range on a slide with an updated version

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a sub() to replace a shape on a ppt slide. The existing shape is a range of cells pasted from Excel (PasteSpecial DataType:=0).

I am trying to replace the pasted range on the slide with an updated version of that same range. I believe my existing code is correct, except for the `.TextEffect.Text` line where I recieve

> Type Mismatch error

Is this because it is not a single cell, but rather a range of cells?

```vb
Sub ReplaceTable()
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim i As Object
  
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
  
    Dim SlideIndex
    Dim SlideShape
    Dim ShapeContent

    For Each i In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
  
        SlideIndex = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i.Row) 'moves to defined slide index
        SlideShape = "Content Placeholder 3" 'selects shape
        ShapeContent = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D9:V24") 'copies new tabular data to replace current table on slide
        myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes(SlideShape).TextEffect.Text = ShapeContent
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You're implicitly trying to assign the `.Value` of a multi-cell range, which is a 2D array, to `.Text`. [`.Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.texteffectformat.text) expects a `String`, not an array. I'm not very strong in PPT, but I expect you want a different approach for a range of Excel cells.

Comment: Is there an alternative approach? I saw .TextFrame.TextRange out on the web, but even when I set the ShapeContent to a range and adjust the end of the code `myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes(SlideShape).TextFrame.TextRange = ShapeContent'
`
I'm still receiving an error. Likely because I'm not applying it correctly.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `PasteSpecial` as you mention early in the question body?

Comment: I was unfamiliar with approach, as in the `PasteSpecial` scenario mentioned, I'm creating a new slide (not replacing existing content) like this:


`'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 16) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

'Copy Excel Range
  Rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0  '0 = ppPasteDefault - if image = 2
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)`

Comment: Solved by deleting shape and then replacing, as so:

`ShapeContent.Copy
    myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes(SlideShape).Delete
    myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes.PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by deleting original shape and then replacing, as so:

```
ShapeContent.Copy 
myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes(SlideShape).Delete
myPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
```